# What is wrong with my approach to Javascript Inheritance?

Tags: javascript

I know there are tons of ways of doing JS inheritance. I am trying to do something here, where I am passing in **rows** into my sub class, and i want to pass it through to the super class at constructor time :

```
function AbstractTableModel(rows) {

    this.showRows = function() {
        alert('rows ' + this.rows);
    }
}

function SolutionTableModel(rows)  {

    this.prototype = new AbstractTableModel(rows);

    this.show = function() {
        this.protoype.showRows();
    };
}

var stm = new SolutionTableModel(3);

stm.show();
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/YuqPX/2/

It doesnt seem to work because the prototype methods are not flowing down :( Any ideas?

Comment: `this.prototype` it the property `prototype` of the create object but you want to the one of the _constructor_ `SolutionTableModel`, so you need to assign it to `SolutionTableModel.prototype`.

Comment: Don't try to set the prototype on the instance, set it on the SolutionTableModel function.

Comment: dont quite understand the first comment. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AbstractTableModel(rows) {
  this.rows = rows;
  this.showRows = function() {
    alert('rows ' + this.rows);
  }
}

function SolutionTableModel(rows) {
  var soln = Object.create(new AbstractTableModel(rows));
  soln.show = function() {
    this.showRows();
  };
  return soln;
}
var solution = new SolutionTableModel(5);
solution.show();
```

This is one way of doing the object inheritance.  This method is most elegant in my opinion and can be found in detail [here](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuqPX/7/)

Comment: like it :) it's the most java-like solution, so good for me :)

Comment: agree with @Braden here,elegant indeed.

Comment: But this method is inefficient... you just use something like durable constructor pattern and Prototypal Inheritance, and whenever you call subtype constructor you call Object.create() method and superType constructor, and creating something like standalone object than inherit from supertype instance

Comment: how inefficient is it? If I need to use this constructor 3 times during someone using my program, is it that much of a problem?

Answer (score 4):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/YuqPX/6/)

First you must define `this.rows`

```
function AbstractTableModel(rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.showRows = function() {
        alert('rows ' + this.rows);
    };
}
```

Second, if you want to inherit from `AbstractTableModel` you ought to do so...

```
function SolutionTableModel(rows)  {
    AbstractTableModel.call(this, rows);

    this.show = function() {
        this.showRows();
    };
}

SolutionTableModel.prototype = new AbstractTableModel();

var stm = new SolutionTableModel(3);

stm.show();
```

**/==============================================================================/**

Also you can use Parasitic Combination Inheritance Pattern, if you want to avoid calling base constructor twice:

```
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType) {
    var prototype = Object.create(superType.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subType,
            enumerable: true
        }
    });
    subType.prototype = prototype;
}

function AbstractTableModel(rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.showRows = function () {
        alert('rows ' + this.rows);
    };
}

function SolutionTableModel(rows) {
    AbstractTableModel.call(this, rows);

    this.show = function () {
        this.showRows();
    };
}

inheritPrototype(AbstractTableModel, SolutionTableModel);

var stm = new SolutionTableModel(3);

stm.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function AbstractTableModel(rows) {
    this.rows = rows;        
}

AbstractTableModel.prototype.showRows = function() {
    console.log('rows ' + this.rows);
}

function SolutionTableModel(rows)  {
    AbstractTableModel.call(this, rows);

    this.show = function() {
        this.showRows();
    };
}

SolutionTableModel.prototype = Object.create(AbstractTableModel.prototype);

var stm = new SolutionTableModel(3);

stm.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working example based on what you have done **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/YuqPX/8/)**:

```
function AbstractTableModel(rows) {
    this.showRows = function () {
        alert('rows ' + rows);
    }
}

function SolutionTableModel(rows) {
    var self = this;
    this.prototype = new AbstractTableModel(rows);
    this.show = function () {
        self.prototype.showRows();
    };
}

var stm = new SolutionTableModel(3);
stm.show();
```

1. In your class `AbstractTableModel` there is no `this.rows` just use `rows` directly.
2. The same catch in the second class `SolutionTableModel`. I prefer to define variable `self` that points to the created instance of the object.
3. You miss type `protoype` it should be `prototype`